# Partial Differential equation and wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

Consider the following pde:

$U_{tt}-c^2U_{xx}=0$ with boundary conditions $U_{x}=0$ at $x=0$ and $x=\pi$
For initial conditions,
$u(x,0)=1$ if $x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$ if $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$
and $U_{t}(x,0)$ $=$ $0$

Find the solution $U(x,t)$ for $t>0$

My attempt:
After doing all the initial conditions and finding a general solution, I got

$\sum_{n=1}A_ncos(nx)=1$
so I multiply both sides by $cos(mx)$ and get
$\sum_{n=1}A_ncos(nx)cos(mx)=cos(mx)$

then I integrate both sides by $x=0$ to $\pi$, the limits of the integral are not correct, may someone please tell me why?

Comment: Hint: Consider $(\partial_t-c\partial_x)(\partial_t +c\partial_x)$, and solve for each factor at a time.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking I only want an explanation for what the limits of the integral should be.

Comment: You've set the sum of $u(x,0) = 1 = A_{n} \cos(nx)$, so the integration limits should be the same as where $u(x,0) = 1$.